# maven override/replace file into WEB-INF/classes

Tags: spring, maven, war

I want to override/replace my spring config xml file with specified location file while package as war.
And I do not want to use filter plugin (filter plugin must to use dolloar placeholder, it will run with error while local deploy), is there any plugin or setting I can use to do this?

project structure as follow:

```
ROOT
----config
    ----prd
        ----spring-servlet.xml
        ----web.xml
----src
    ----main
        ----java
        ----resources
            ----spring-servlet.xml
        ----webapp
....
```

My pom.xml is like as follow:

```
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prd</id>
        <properties>
            <filterDir>prd</filterDir>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>${basedir}/config/${filterDir}/web.xml</webXml>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>config/${filterDir}</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes/</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

run maven use :mvn clean package -P prd.

Will work fine if not set tartgetPath, file copied to web root.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***copy-resources*** of maven to do this.

Example maven code should be like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-web.xml</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <outputDirectory>your-target-directory</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>source-directory</directory>
                        <!--You can also mention files too-->
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Read more about [copy-resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) for correct implementation.